# Symfony3 custom user provider not called

Tags: php, symfony

I created a DBAL that uses pure sql and I want to use with symfony3 without doctrine. For that purpouse, I have to create a custom user provider. I followed [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html) to the letter but the provider is not even called. My security.yml is...

```
security:
    providers:
        blue_dot_provider:
            id: vocallo.user_provider

    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            anonymous: ~
            provider: blue_dot_provider
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                always_use_default_target_path: true
                default_target_path: app_homepage

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/vocallo, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Did I miss something in the configuration?

Comment: I put my provider line under form_login.  Not sure if it makes a difference.  Also, comment out the line under access_control until you get the provider sorted.  access_control can sometimes do funny things.  And of course be sure to clear the cache if you are not in development mode.

Comment: I did all that and it still doesn't work. It instantiates the user provider but it doesn't call the loadUserByUsername() method. DoaAuthenticationProvider is instantiated and it receives my user provider in the consturctor but none of its public methods are called including authenticate(). It's wierd

Comment: Is MyProvider::supportsClass being called?

Comment: Under main: I have pattern:  ^/ but I again I don't think it will make a difference.  And I assume what you posted matches your actual security.yml file?  You did not "clean" things up for the question?  Nothing funky going on with login_path?  You are not intercepting POST login_path with your own code?  No other custom listeners and what not?

Comment: No, none of those methods are called

Comment: No, that is the security.yml. I only putted provider config key under form_login. Also, I checked the profiler, it registeres my user provider as the user provider but it is not going to check_path route. It only goes to my app_login path. Also, $error and $lastUsername from loginAction() are all null.

Comment: Have you ever gotten the standard form_login setup working without a custom user provider?  Just using the all the standard stuff?  If not then maybe start over and just get the basic login working.  Security can be tricky.  Might even go so far as to create a brand new project.  I could post my security.yml file if you want but I don't really see anything wrong with yours.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so too. I'll give it a try